# Classification of groups of order 8

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, groups-enumeration

In this document, there is a classification of all groups of order 8:

http://www2.lawrence.edu/fast/corrys/Math300/8Groups.pdf

I understood it all until the part in the third page that says:

"$b^2$ must have order $2$, so that $b \in H = \langle a \rangle $"

Why must $b$ be in the group generated by $a$? This isn't obvious to me.

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: @Alnitak: If you do not get an answer check out "A Course in Group Theory" by John F. Humphreys (ISBN 0198534590); the book classifies (among other things) small groups up to order 31.

Comment: This is the case because the author assumes that every element of $G-H$ has order $4$. Since $b^2$ has order $2$, $b^2$ can't be in $G-H$. See the first sentence of subcase 2b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant paragraph (named "*Subcase 2b*") has the assumption that every element of $G-H$, and therefore specifically $b$, has order $4$. Since $b$ has order $4$, $b^2$ has order $2$. Since the order of $b^2$ is *not* $4$, we must have $b^2 \notin (G-H)$ by the standing assumption. This means $b \in H = \langle a \rangle$.

Comment: But why $b^2 \notin (G-H)$ just because it's order isn't $4$? Isn't $H = \langle x \rangle $? What does $b$ has to do with $x$?

Comment: @Alnitak Because by _assumption_, all elements of $G-H$ has order $4$. Therefore an element that doesn't have order $4$ (such as $b^2$) cannot be an element of that set. $H = \langle a \rangle$ is the complement of $G-H$ and $b^2$ must be in there.

Comment: Oh, now I see. It is indeed obvious... maybe I'm too tired. Thanks a lot!