# Classifying groups of order 8

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm trying to classify all groups of order 8 up to isomorphism and I'm stuck. I was wondering whether someone could help me move forward and also comment on my general approach.

Suppose $G$ is a group of order 8. If $G$ is abelian, then the possible isomorphism classes are given by the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups: $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_2}$, $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_4}$ and $\mathbb{Z_8}$ .

Now suppose $G$ is not abelian. Because $|G|=2^3$, the group must contain subgroups $N, K$ of orders 4 and 2. Furthermore $[G:N]=2$ and thus this group must be normal.

Suppose $N \cap K = \{1\}$. Then G is a semidirect product of $N$ and $K$. Obviously $K \simeq \mathbb{Z_2}$ and for $N$ we have to options: $N \simeq \mathbb{Z_4}$ or $N \simeq \mathbb{Z_2 \times Z_2}$. In the first case we know that ${\rm Aut}(N) \simeq U(\mathbb{Z_4})\simeq \mathbb{Z_2}$. The only possible homomorphisms $\phi:K \to{\rm Aut}(N) $ are the trivial homomorphism or the natural isomorphism. Calculating $N \rtimes_{\phi} K$ yields $D_8$.

If $N \simeq \mathbb{Z_2 \times Z_2}$, we will have ${\rm Aut}(N) \simeq S_3$. Here I'm stuck. For instance, if $\phi$ permutes two non-trivial elements of $N$, then we get the semidirect product $\mathbb{Z_2 \times Z_2} \rtimes_{\phi} \mathbb{Z_2}$. I have no idea what this group is. Furthermore, when researching the answer, I found that the other non-abelian group of order 8 is actually the quaternion group $Q_8$ which cannot be obtained as a semidirect product (which would fit in the other case where $N \cap K \neq \{1\}$. I have no idea how to even begin to think about this case.

Comment: "Classify" would be the usual term, rather than "categorise", which might be confused with having something to do with category theory.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722495/classification-of-groups-of-order-8) for more details. The last page of the pdf-file gives the answer. The classification of non-abelian groups of order $p^3$ is due to Hölder.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I stumbled on this proof already but it uses quite elementary methods (no Sylow) so I thought it wasn't the 'standard' approach to classifying groups

Comment: It is really good for groups of order $8$, because you don't need more. For the "standard" proof, see the classification of groups of order $p^3$.

Comment: Your second group is the dihedral group again, but this time instead of being realized as $\langle r\rangle \rtimes\langle s\rangle$, you are realizing it as, for example, $\{e,rs,r^2,r^3s\}\rtimes \langle s\rangle$.

Comment: ah, I see, thank you! I suppose there isn't any general method for finding non-split extensions of $N$ by $K$?

Comment: [This](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/index.html) might help.